# react-native-navigation: startTabBasedApp and switch to tab

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

How can I **startTabBasedApp** with focused specific tab.
By default it opens first tab. But I want conditionally focus tab when I **startTabBasedApp**

Answer (score 0):

```
tabsStyle: { 
    initialTabIndex: 1, // optional, the default selected bottom tab. 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
     tabs: [
        {
            screen: "screen1",
            icon: require("../sharedAssets/image.png"),
            label: "label1",
        },
        {
            screen: "screen2"
            icon: require("../sharedAssets/image2.png"),
            label: "label2",
        }
    ],
    tabsStyle: {
        initialTabIndex: 1, // optional, the default selected bottom tab. Default: 0
    }
})
```